# How can I install STREAMS in Linux?

Tags: linux, streams, fast-streams

I searched on Google, but found nothing useful. I use SUSE now, how can I install LiS on my computer?

I'm hoping for a download link.

Comment: What exactly you want to install?

Comment: May he means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS ?

Comment: @pbm LiS maybe ... I want the write some STREAMS test code in my Linux.

Comment: Unless you have some legacy systems that absolutely require STREAMS, follow the advice of the kernel developers who consider STREAMS "technically inadequate". Add to that the abandoned state of the libraries that simulate it and you are asking for pain and unhappiness. STREAMS wasn't so great when it was native to SVR4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wikipedia article on STREAMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS):

*excerpt*

> - The Linux kernel does not include STREAMS functionality. The kernel  developers consider it technically inadequate, and the compatibility layers in Linux for other operating systems convert STREAMS operations into sockets as early as possible.[[14](http://www.openss7.org/streams.html)](http://lkml.org/lkml/1998/6/28/138)
>
>   - LiS (Linux STREAMS) adds STREAMS functionality on Linux[[15](http://www.openss7.org/streams_pkg.html)](http://www2.linuxjournal.com/article/3086),[[16](http://www.openss7.org/package/streams-0.9.2.4/)](http://lis.wanware.com/)
>   - OpenSS7 offers Fast STREAMS on Linux.[[17]](http://www.openss7.org/download.html)

#### OpenSS7

If you're on a Red Hat based distro, [OpenSS7 provides RPMs](http://www.openss7.org/download.html) for STREAMS so it should be trivial to at least install it.

#### LiS

I also came across this URL, titled: [Introduction to LiS](http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/index.html). This page seems to be what you're looking for. It includes links to download LiS as well as installation instructions.

- [Downloads LiS](http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/download.html)
- [Installation Instructions](http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/install.html)

Seems pretty straightforward to install it. You'll need tools such as `gcc`, `autotest`, `make`, etc. installed. Depending on your distro these should be easy enough to get.

The steps to install it:

```
$ cd /usr/src/LiS-2.16 (Or wherever you installed the files)
$ make
$ make install
```

Looks like these steps assume you're root when doing the installation. I hightly suggest you read the [Installation of LiS](http://www.gcom.com/home/linux/lis/install.html) guide. It covers installation and configuration of the software.

#### 32-bit vs. 64-bit

As of version 2.19.2 there isn't any support for 64-bit. So just something to be aware of.

- https://www.dialogic.com/den/forums/p/9246/34706.aspx

#### UPDATE #1

In digging more into the gcom.com website it appears that they've discontinued support for LiS.

*excerpt*

> The LiS-2.18 version described by this documentation is the final
>   version of LiS to be published on the Gcom FTP site. It is possible
>   that others in the LiS community may organize a maintenance method for
>   this package. To be apprised of developments in this area subscribe to
>   the LiS discussion group and watch for announcements.
>
> Gcom no longer supports LiS for use with anything other than Gcom
>   products.  Please consult your software/hardware vendor for LiS
>   support.  If you are interested in complete protocol solutions for
>   Linux, please contact sales@gcom.com.

More digging lead to this [URL which has LiS 2.19.0](ftp://ftp.uk.metaswitch.com/pub/LiS/LiS-2.19.0.tgz). I was able to download it successfully and the tarball appears to be intact.

**NOTE:** The above URL was ferreted out from this IBM technote, titled: [Where to get LiS (Linux Streams)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=1066&uid=swg21247997).

#### Linux Fast-STREAMS project?

I found this note on the openss7 site, on a page titled: [Linux STREAMS (LiS) Installation and Reference Manual](http://www.openss7.org/manuals/LiS.html).

*excerpt*

> Note: The original LiS package from GCOM is no longer actively
>   maintained by either GCOM or the OpenSS7 Project: use the OpenSS7
>   Linux Fast-STREAMS package http://www.openss7.org/STREAMS.html
>   instead.

Of course the URL above is broken, I was able to find this Fast-STREAMS project page on the openss7 project page here, titled: [Linux Fast-STREAMS](http://www.openss7.org/streams.html).

Continuing my expedition on the openss7 website I found this page, titled: [Linux Fast-STREAMS (streams) Release](http://www.openss7.org/streams_pkg.html). This page included both links to the deprecated LiS project as well as the new project Fast-STREAMS, which they appear to be just calling streams. This [link to the latest version, 0.9.2.4](http://www.openss7.org/package/streams-0.9.2.4/) of streams, includes tarballs, source RPMS, and binary RPMS.

This page seems to be what you're looking for, though the packages are provided for CentOS 5.2, they might be rebuilt for CentOS 6.x.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for instructions on installing `LiS`.

Comment: @JosephR. - links [[15]] and [[16]] look to be partially that.

Comment: My bad... I didn't follow the links.

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah one of them (wanware) is dead.

Comment: The LiS download link need a usename and password!

Comment: +1 exhaustively researched, unfortunately the question is weak.

Comment: @msw - Good addition to the site, still don't really understand how to use it, but it was a pretty large hole in the internet so hopefully for the 5 people looking for this in the future they'll be happy 8-).